# How to interpret MAX7219 timing diagram?

Tags: spi, max7219

I'm trying to connect this module to atmega32u4 (16 MHz):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Everything seems mostly working, but I have a question:
how much time is needed for the latch to take effect?
I.e., is a delay needed between SLAVE_DESELECT and SLAVE_SELECT in the following example?

```
#define SLAVE_SELECT    PORTB &= ~(1 << PB0)
#define SLAVE_DESELECT  PORTB |= 1 << PB0
...
DDRB |= 1 << PB0;
PORTB |= 1 << PB0;      // begin high (unselected)
....
  SLAVE_SELECT;
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_DEVICES; i++)
    writeWord(0x0A, 0x0F); // brightness
  SLAVE_DESELECT;   

  SLAVE_SELECT;
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_DEVICES; i++)
    writeWord(0x0C, 0x01);
  SLAVE_DESELECT;
```

(SCK frequency is 4MHz in my configuration.)

Also, I do not understand how to interpret the timing diagram from [datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX7219-MAX7221.pdf):

[image: timing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no delay is needed. I have used MAX7219 with Arduinos at 8 MHz SPI clock, back to back writes were not an issue.

The timing diagram just shows chip select (Load) going low, 16 bits going out with the clock, and chip select going high.

I use SPI.transfer, with port manipulation like you did, but as an example here with digitalWrite:

```
digitalWrite (ssPin, LOW);
SPI.transfer(address); // from 1 to 15, or 0 if using NOP
SPI.transfer(dataToSend); // varies by register. 1 to 8 are data display, 9+ are command registers
digitalWrite (ssPin, HIGH);
```

Replace the digitalWrite with your SLAVE_SELECT; & SLAVE_DESELECT; commands. For a single MAX7219, I would have 5 of these in setup() to configure the intensity, Normal mode, # of digits (scan limit), not Mode B, and display test.  Others might do that as 5 function calls. Or 1 function call to do all 5.

```
SLAVE_SELECT;
SPI.transfer(address); 
SPI.transfer(dataToSend); 
SLAVE_SELECT;
// no delay needed here,even with 8 MHz SPI clock
SLAVE_SELECT;
SPI.transfer(address); 
SPI.transfer(dataToSend); 
SLAVE_SELECT;
```

And if you are bit-banging this, the transfer will be even slower:

```
writeWord(0x0A, 0x0F); // brightness
```

Comment: But the question was about CS latching, not about SPI bus clock. And as far as I know, Arduino digitalwrite function takes many assembly instructions versus the direct port write macro, so in some cases timing could be violated. But not in this case with only 16MHz CPU clock.

Comment: The fastest one can toggle a pin using Direct Port Manipulation is 8 MHz, which is 125 nS, so the 50nS is easily met.

Answer (score 0):

Tcsw is 50ns minimum. Page 3 of datasheet.
While a 16 MHz MCU will have a 62.5ns cycle time, it does not hurt to put a NOP or two there, to let slowly rising signals to settle.

Comment: In my setup microcontroller frequency is 16 MHz and SCK frequency is 4 MHz. In the answer you refer to microcontroller frequency or to SCK frequency?

Comment: I've corrected my answer with correct MCU clock.